# 15mm to 3/4" BSP flexible tap connector

Tags: plumbing, faucet, uk

I am about to set up a new bath mixer tap, which has standard 3/4" thread connectors. My water supply is a standard 15mm pipe with isolation valves fitted. I was planning to get compression 15mm to 3/4" BSP flexi connector - but here's where I ran into a problem.  All of the plumbing supply stores in the area (both DIY and trade) have these flexi connectors with 3/4" female end (i.e. the nut that screws onto the tap) and 15mm male thread with a compression nut on the other end.  I need the 15mm end to also be a female nut to screw onto the isolation valve.

I know I can just cut a short piece of 15mm pipe and fit to the isolation valve - and then go with the flexi connector as above, but I want to minimise the number of connection points.

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

But with 15mm on one end and 3/4" on the other end.  Is there a specific term for it?  How do I search for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nut on a 15mm compression fitting in the UK is normally 1/2 inch BSP. So you can remove the nut on a 15mm compression fitting and screw on a hose with a 1/2 inch BSP "tap connector" style fitting.

Unfortunately while I can find hoses with 1/2 inch BSP "tap connector" style fittings on both ends, I can't seem to find one with 1/2 inch BSP on one end and 3/4 inch BSP on the other, so this doesn't really help in your specific case.

I think a short piece of 15mm copper pipe is probably your best bet. I really wouldn't stress about an extra compression joint in the run.